# Replacing an older Jacuzzi jetted tub waterfall side spout

Tags: plumbing, installation

I have a jacuzzi tub, put in the home in 2002.  However, my gold waterfall spout is broken and needs replacement.  Do they make it in a chrome finish?  If so, do they also make the controls that are square in chrome (opposite side of spout).  If there are no replacement parts, does anyone know the actual cut-out dimensions for replacing?

Thank you

Comment: We're going to need a little more to go on, like a picture or two , model number.

Comment: Aren't you able to take a measurement? It should be a whole number, like 4" centers. The shopping part of your question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I have a chrome  "waterfall" spout on my Jacuzzi whirlpool tub that was installed in 1998. When we purchased it they had a variety of spouts and on/off handles in many shapes and finishes. I would search for a Jacuzzi phone number and call them directly. Go to jacuzzi.com to find a phone number to call.